# PHP Sessions expiry time - keeping session alive for a specific number of minutes/hours/days

Tags: php, session, cookies, timeout

I have a site that creates a Session for shopping carts.

```
$_SESSION['cart']=array();
```

It seems as if the server automatically kills the session after X time of inactivity, I assume this is set in php.ini (but my host does not grant me access, they just let me tell them the changes, so I cannot play around! :().

Is there a better way to keep the sessions alive for example for 2 days or for a specific number of minutes/hours?

Comment: change the various `session.*` settings using `ini_set()` **BEFORE** you call session_start(): http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Call [`session_set_cookie_params()`](http://php.net/session_set_cookie_params) before you call [`session_start()`](http://php.net/session_start) in your scripts:

```
$session_lifetime = 3600 * 24 * 2; // 2 days
session_set_cookie_params ($session_lifetime);
session_start();
// ...
```

From the [documentation](http://php.net/session_set_cookie_params):

> **`session_set_cookie_params()`**
>   Set cookie parameters defined in the php.ini file. The effect of this function only lasts for the duration of the script. Thus, you need to call `session_set_cookie_params()` for every request and before `session_start()` is called.

Alternatively, you could update your php.ini file's `session.cookie_lifetime` directive to 2 days (in seconds).

Comment: ouh... your answer is better than mine ;)

Answer (score 1):

set a cookie and change in you config that the session use cookies

```
session_start();
set_cookie("PHPSESSID", session_id(), time() + 3600 * 2);
```

this keep alive your session for 2 hours

Comment: this doesn't work unfortunately.. see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38566461/keep-only-specific-sessions-alive-for-several-weeks?noredirect=1#comment64522757_38566461